# In Hilt, How can I Inject a context in a non activity/ fragment class using field injection?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I have a Exception Handling class

```
class IOException : BaseException {
    @EntryPoint
    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    interface AnalyticsServiceProviderEntryPoint {
        fun analyticsService(): AnalyticsService
    }
 private val hiltEntryPoint = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(**Need Context**, AnalyticsServiceProviderEntryPoint::class.java)
    val analyticsService = hiltEntryPoint.analyticsService()

}
```

If I see this offical [link](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#not-supported), it says

> In this example, you must use the ApplicationContext to retrieve the
> entry point because the entry point is installed in SingletonComponent

What If I don't have the context in the class and in the function body which I will use and I don't want to use from Constructor Injection as well?

I only want to use the field injection. How can I access it, since I don't have the context.

Comment: So to clear. You want to get `@ApplicationContext`  in `IOException`  class. But, You don't want to pass it from constructor from `IOException(context: Context)`  right? You want to do it in the class itself?

Comment: yes i dont want to pass from constructor or from function, i can't always pass it from some class like IOException(context)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to get `applicationContext` from dagger-hilt `ApplicationContextModule`? Its already provided by this module in your app and you can get that probably. You need to use the qualifer also

```
  @Provides
  @ApplicationContext
  Context provideContext() {
    return applicationContext;
  }
```

Comment: I tried that, by using a field injection but it said: lateinit property context has not been initialized

Comment: this doesn't really work. Unless we misunderstood something. Can you give an example please?

Answer (score 0):

In your application add a `companion object` with `lateinit var applicationContext` and initialize the variable when the application is initialized like:

```
companion object {
    lateinit var applicationContext: Context
        private set
```

then you have an static variable with the application context and you can you something like:

```
 private val hiltEntryPoint = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(Application.applicationContext, AnalyticsServiceProviderEntryPoint::class.java)
```

I can't think of anything else to do what you want to do

Comment: it might work, but problem is. That from where I'm using I can't call MyApplication.applicationContext. Since that is in another module, if I inherit it, it will have circular dependency.